# How can i write in text Files on a FTP Server?

Tags: java, file, text, ftp

I'm working on a Project where Users can upload their own files etc. 
And i want to make a list with all files.
But how i can i write in text files on a FTP Server?
Heres my code:

```
public static void write(String url, String password, String name, String text, String pathOnServer) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect(url, 21);
        client.login(name, password);

        OutputStream out1 = client
                .storeFileStream("/Centio/Configs/User/" + UsernameUtil.getUsername() + "/ConfigList.txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out1));

        bufferedWriter1.write(text);
        bufferedWriter1.newLine();

        bufferedWriter1.close();
        out1.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a MAJOR warning: you do not control the client. Everybody who gets your jar into their hands can decompile it, change it and then can probably upload files to whatever directory they want.

Comment: My jar is not on the FTP Server. Only txt files

Comment: that is the point. I *hope* every user has their own name-password pair and those are not one set of credentials for the entire ftp account.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: It does not work ^^

Comment: @RobinCirex We cannot help you unless you tell us what error you are getting. So firstly you need to add `e.printStackTrace();` to your catch block (You should almost never have an empty catch clause). Once you have added that, you should be getting an error when you run the code. Read the error and see if you can work it out, or you can copy the error and edit you question to include it. Other things: Have you tried checking if `ConfigList.txt` exists?, Can your code even reach the server?, Is the username or password wrong?

Comment: Maybe try flushing the writer before closing,